# Error message on NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate Protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am actually handling download/upload file and keeping tracked of the progress. It's working well. However, I am just wondering what if something goes wrong and I don't see any methods in this delegate handling the error. Here is the methods from `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`:

```
/*
 * Messages related to the operation of a task that writes data to a
 * file and notifies the delegate upon completion.
 */
@protocol NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate <NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>

/* Sent when a download task that has completed a download.  The delegate should 
 * copy or move the file at the given location to a new location as it will be 
 * removed when the delegate message returns. URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: will
 * still be called.
 */
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
                              didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location;

@optional
/* Sent periodically to notify the delegate of download progress. */
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
                                           didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
                                      totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten
                              totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

/* Sent when a download has been resumed. If a download failed with an
 * error, the -userInfo dictionary of the error will contain an
 * NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData key, whose value is the resume
 * data. 
 */
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
                                      didResumeAtOffset:(int64_t)fileOffset
                                     expectedTotalBytes:(int64_t)expectedTotalBytes;

@end
```

Just wondering how to throw back the error message, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your delegate conform to [NSURLSessionTaskDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate) and implement:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
              task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
```

**EDIT** to clarify further, please see [the doc for NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate_protocol/), notice near the top where it says:

> In addition to these methods, be sure to implement the methods in the
>   NSURLSessionTaskDelegate and NSURLSessionDelegate protocols to handle
>   events common to all task types and session-level events,
>   respectively.

The idea is that the url session's delegate may conform any of those protocols.  The method you're looking for, the one that indicates error, is just more generic than a download task, it can happen on any sort of session task, so they put it in a more abstract protocol.

Comment: I did not because I only see three delegate methods their. Can you also include the relationship between `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` and `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`?

Comment: Yes, in the place where you declare your conformance to NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate, just add `<NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>` and implement the error method.

Comment: Can you please include to the answers so that people will know because for beginner like us. We don't know. And what's relationship between these two protocols?

Comment: Please raise up the post as much as you can. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean